# Maven include specific folder in JAR

Tags: maven, build, jar

I have this in my POM:

```
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>resources</directory>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

And I have this folder structure:

```
project_directory
├─src
│ └─etc
└─resources
  ├─A
  ├─B
  └─C
```

But when I build I only get `A`, `B`, and `C` in the JAR, but I want it to include the whole `resources` folder. Is there a way to do this besides adding another folder under resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<targetPath>` of [`<resource>`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Resources):

```
    ...  
    <resource>
      <directory>${project.basedir}/resources</directory>
      <targetPath>resources</targetPath>   
    </resource>
    ...
```

Note: [`basedir` is deprecated in favour of `project.basedir`.](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.1/maven-model-builder/#Model_Interpolation)